# Collections.unmodifiableList and defensive copy

Tags: java, collections, unmodifiable

If I write

```
List<Integer> a1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> a2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(a1);
```

`a2` is read-only but if I write

```
a1.set(0,10);
```

then `a2` is also modified.

If in the API is said:

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified collection. This method
>   allows modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal
>   collections.

then, why if I modify the original collection also the target-copied collection is modified?

Maybe did I misunderstand the meaning and if so what's the way to
write a defensive copy of that collection?

Comment: If you wanted to have an unmodifiable version of a1 then you could clone a1 and make that an unmodifiable list. Then updates to a1 would not effect a2.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, you understood it correctly. The idea is that the object returned by `umodifiableCollection` can't directly be changed, but could change through other means (effectively by changing the internal collection directly).

As long as something has access to the internal list, the "unmodifiable" collection could be changed.

That's why you *usually* construct a unmodifiable collection and make sure that nothing can ever get to the internal list:

```
Collection<Integer> myUmodifiableCollection = Collection.umodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

Since nothing ever gets a reference to the `List` created by `asList`, this is a truly unmodifiable collection.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to copy the original collection/list at all, which avoids using memory and computing power.

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides the [`ImmutableCollection`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html) class (and its subclasses such as [`ImmutableList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)) which provide true immutable collections (usually by copying the source).

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` already returns a fixed size List. So why do we need to additionally decorate it using `Collections.unmodifiableList()`?I see both you and @assylias have used the same idiom. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Geek: While `Arras.asList()` returns a fixed size List, it does not return an unmodifiable one. You can still change elements by using `set(int,T)`. `Collections.unmodifiableList()` "fixes" that by disallowing this. But in any real-world code I'd probably just use the Guava `ImmutableList` (linked to above), as it is shorter to write, very clear and always make sure that nothing can "leak".

Answer (score 12):

> Maybe did I misunderstand the meaning and if so what's the way to write a defensive copy of that collection?

Typically, you would use it that way:

```
private List<Integer> a1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

public List<Integer> getUnmodifiable() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(a1);
}
```

Someone who calls `getUnmodifiable` **and** does not have access to the internal of your class (i.e. they can't acces the private variable `a1`), won't be able to modify the returned list.

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` already returns a fixed size List. So why do we need to additionally decorate it using `Collections.unmodifiableList()`? What am I missing?

Comment: You can't add to a1 but you can set any item to something different.

Comment: @assylias Actually you could modify the internal of  objects in the list, but you can't use set() method to replace a old object with another one in the list.

Answer (score 4):

If you were looking to keep `a1` mutable and make an immutable copy of it without Guava, this is one way you could do it.

```
    List<Integer> a1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> a2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(a1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 10 you may do `List.copyOf()`:

```
List<Integer> a1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> a2 = List.copyOf(a1);
```

After that, changes to `a1` are not visible through `a2`, because `List.copyOf()` copies the contents of your list to a new one. The copy is unmodifiable. But make sure to read the documentation on the method before using it, because it does not work with lists containing `null` values.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you can't modify the list via `a2`.

Modifying the `a1` list will indeed modify what you see in `a2` - this is intended.

Just dont have a public way to access the list `a1`, and you should have what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

the API says it **internal collections** in your case the collection is not internal

the point is that when you have a private list in class an a gettet for that list, then you may want callers of the getter to not be able to modify the list in witch case you'll have to return an umodifiable list. otherwise the returned list is just a reference to your internal/private list and thus its content can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
Collections.unmodifiableList(a1);
```

returns a wrapper over the original collection whose modifier methods throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

The wrapper is read-through, meaning that if you modify `a1`, the changes reflect on the wrapped collection `a2`.

Comment: Actually you could modify the internal of objects in the list, but you can't use set() method to replace a old object with another one.

Answer (score 0):

`a1` and `a2` will reference the same data (memory).

the un-mofifiable part comes , only with `a2` as entry.

imaging if you are passing `a2` to a method where you expect the method to be idempotent. such cases `a2` helps.

in summary you cant modify data using `a2` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need unmodifiable and immutable list or in other words unmodifiable copy of the source list without any dependency to other libraries try this:

```
Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.list(Collections.enumeration(sourceList)))
```

`Collections.list()` copies values from its enumeration.