# AsyncListDiffer implement. How mReadOnlyList work?

Tags: android, listadapter

I am looking at the implementation of `AsyncListDiffer` in Android and I am stuck at one point.
How is the `mReadOnlyList` is used for?

```
public class AsyncListDiffer<T> {
    private List<T> mList;        

    @NonNull
    private List<T> mReadOnlyList = Collections.emptyList();

    @NonNull
    public List<T> getCurrentList() {
        return mReadOnlyList;
    }

    public void submitList(final List<T> newList) {
        ...
        if (newList == null) {

            mList = null;
            mReadOnlyList = Collections.emptyList();
            return;
        }

        if (mList == null) {
            mList = newList;
            mReadOnlyList = Collections.unmodifiableList(newList);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void latchList(@NonNull List<T> newList, @NonNull DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult) {
        mList = newList;
        mReadOnlyList = Collections.unmodifiableList(newList);
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(mUpdateCallback);
    }
}
```

And `getCurrentList()` only access in

```
public abstract class ListAdapter<T, VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {
    ...
    private final AsyncListDiffer<T> mHelper;

    protected T getItem(int position) {
        return mHelper.getCurrentList().get(position);
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return mHelper.getCurrentList().size();
    }
}
```

Why they don't simple create 2 methods like `getItem(int position)` and `getItemCount()` in `AsyncListDiffer` without create a `mReadOnlyList`?
Because I see when `newList` change, `mReadOnlyList` also change
[Collections.unmodifiableList and defensive copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111073/collections-unmodifiablelist-and-defensive-copy)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is simply that you can use `AsyncListDiffer` directly and not only via `ListAdapter`. (And in fact the docs recommend doing this when you can't inherit from the `ListAdapter` base class for some reason.)

When using `AsyncListDiffer` directly, you can get the current list using `getCurrentList` (which is after all a public method) and use it for a variety of purposes, not only those listed in `ListAdapter`. So the `AsyncListDiffer` always maintains this list for retrieval via `getCurrentList`, without allowing other classes to modify the underlying list.